# How can prepare ppb solution of sodium

Tags: physical-chemistry

How can prepare 1000ppb solution of sodium from sodium chloride salt in one litre.

Comment: Welcome to Chem SE! If you haven't yet, take the [tour] and visit the [help]. This question is likely to be closed, as we expect posters to include some of their own thoughts/attempts at solving a problem.

Comment: The title is misleading since you want to prepare a concentration in the order of ppm and not ppb, which would be a bit more difficult since sodium is ubiquitous. Also note that non-standard units such as ppm and ppb should actually be avoided; preferably use an unambiguous unit such as mg/kg.

Comment: @Loong - Like you point about sodium being ubiquitous. Not sure what special precautions might be necessary for ppb levels of Na. Obviously at least distilled water not deionized, and very clean glassware. Not sure if you could leach that much sodium from glassware or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume 1 liter of solution has a mass of 1 kg.

1000 ppb = 1 ppm = 1 mg/liter.

Sodium chloride is only 39.34 % sodium so you'd need 2.54 mg.

It is tough to weigh out that little so weigh 2.54 g and dissolve in 1.000 liter volumetric flask. Use a volumetric pipette and take 1.00 ml of that solution and dilute to 1.000 liters in a second volumetric flask.